# Cross Validation and preprocessing tokenizer in python

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, cross-validation

I have a text dataframe which looks like this:

```
        Class       Text
8776    Wirtschaft  Potente Investoren und das liebe Vieh: Ärzte s...
7810    Web         Lokalverbot sei zwar diskriminierend, aber nic...
3658    Kultur      In den 80ern lieferten sie kämpferische Gassen...
318     Etat        Ebru Umar war nach Kritik an Präsident Erdogan...
3014    International   Zahlreiche Menschen in Jaffa niedergestochen, ...
```

the target is to classify the Class.
I want to use svm from sklear you run a classification algorithm.

Right now I am using a text.tokenizer to convert the strings into numeric features:

```
def generatextrain(train_text, test_text, maxwords):
    max_words = maxwords
    tokenize = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, char_level=False)
    tokenize.fit_on_texts(train_text) # fit tokenizer to our training text data
    x_train = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(train_text)
    x_test = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(test_text)
    return x_train, x_test, maxwords
```

as you can see I am only use the train set to fit the tokenizer.

If I want to add PCA to it in a later step, and also implement a cross-validation technique as k-fold von python, what is the right sequence to do so?
From my understanding it is forbidden to use test data in the training part, but how does the tokenizer and pca work then in k-fold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a pipline to tell scikit-learn in advance what preprocessing should be applied:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.StandardScaler(), svm.SVC(C=1))
cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=cv)
```

[Here is a good pipline example using PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#combining-estimators).

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline):

> Pipeline of transforms with a final estimator.
>
> Sequentially apply a list of transforms and a final estimator.
>   Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they
>   must implement fit and transform methods. The final estimator only
>   needs to implement fit. The transformers in the pipeline can be cached
>   using memory argument

Comment: how does the pipeline works? and how to integrate tokenizer? Will the pipeline then procede the preprocessing step everytime before the training starts?

Comment: I clarified it.